# Difference between '~' and '/' in linux

Tags: linux

What is the difference between ~ and / in Linux environment?

Can anyone please explain the difference?

Answer (score 16):

~ contains the path to the current user home directory (it gets expanded to the **$HOME** env variable). If you run:

```
echo ~
```

It will print this path. Slash character / is used by Linux (and other OSs) as path separator. In Linux additionally if you do:

```
cd /
```

It will bring you to the **root** directory (topmost directory of your filesystem)

Answer (score 11):

Tilde(~) is used to denote a user's home directory whereas slash(/) is used for seperators for filesystem objects in both absolute paths and relative paths. Also it is used for to represent the root directory.

**On a side note:**

~/ is used to denote beginning of a path to a file or directory below the user's home directory.

Answer (score 4):

the simple answer is :
`/` is your root directory
`~` is your home directory

Answer (score 2):

`/` is the character that separates directories. As the first character in a path, it denotes the root directory.

`~` is the character that some shells expand to a user's home directory. See for example "Tilde Expansion" in `man bash`:

> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~'), all of the characters preceding the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if there is no  unquoted  slash)  are
>          considered  a tilde-prefix.  If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted,
>          the characters in the tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible login
>          name.   If this login name is the null string, the tilde is replaced with the value of
>          the shell parameter HOME.  If HOME is unset, the home directory of the user  executing
>          the  shell  is  substituted instead.  Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the
>          home directory associated with the specified login name.
>
> If the tilde-prefix is a `~+`, the value of the shell variable PWD replaces the tilde-prefix.   If the tilde-prefix is a `~-`, the value of the shell variable OLDPWD, if it
>          is set, is substituted.  If the characters following the  tilde  in  the  tilde-prefix
>          consist  of  a  number  N,  optionally prefixed by a `+` or a `-`, the tilde-prefix is
>          replaced with the corresponding element from the directory stack, as it would be  displayed by the dirs builtin invoked with the tilde-prefix as an argument.  If the characters following the tilde in the tilde-prefix consist of a number without  a  leading
>          `+` or `-`, `+` is assumed.
>
> If the login name is invalid, or the tilde expansion fails, the word is unchanged.
>
> Each  variable assignment is checked for unquoted tilde-prefixes immediately following
>          a `:` or the first `=`.  In these cases, tilde expansion is also performed.  Consequently,
>          one  may  use  filenames with tildes in assignments to PATH, MAILPATH, and CDPATH, and
>          the shell assigns the expanded value.

Answer (score 2):

To test this out type
cd / or cd ~
then pwd it will show the exact local